# invalid procedure call or argument excel - Error 5 in a for loop

Tags: excel, vba, object

I have used the below code snippet to write from xls file to txt. Apparently it works for the first 11 lines in the excel and then throws error of invalid procedure @ this line. Can someone please help here, not sure what could be stopping the loop proceed, while commenting this line the loop runs as expected, this function is causing the issue.

oFile.WriteLine currowstring

```
Dim FSO As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(TXTfilepath)
'Set objfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test\PhoneList.csv", 1)
'Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\klukiyan\Desktop\test.txt", 2)

'what to do
Acolumn = 1
currowstring = ""
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Arow = 2 To LastRow
            For Acolumn = 1 To 84
            If Acolumn = Val(Right(Cells(1, Acolumn), 3)) + 3 Then
            currowstring = currowstring & Cells(Arow, Acolumn) & ","
            Acolumn = Acolumn + 1
            Else
            currowstring = currowstring & ","
            End If
            Next Acolumn
            oFile.WriteLine currowstring
            currowstring = ""
            Acolumn = 1
Next Arow
```

Comment: Show exactly the line with the error, people count code lines differently. Then take a look at the value of the `Cells()`, in which the error shows up. E.g., put a `MsgBox(Cells(1,Acolumn).Address)` and look manually. Is it an error or an unexpected String?

Comment: Thanks @Vityata I did check and the issue begins after the 11th row with Data. Although I have 60+ rows of data, only the first 11 lines are writen to the txt file, when the loop begins for the 12th row this line of code - oFile.WriteLine currowstring throws error 5, if I comment this line the loop runs, but has no lines written to the txt file.

Comment: Write `Debug.Print currowstring` and see what is the value that is supposed to be written.

Answer (score 1):

Start from an empty Excel with some dummy data, try writing as less as possible, hardcoding with some magic numbers and go step-by-step from the small, hardcoded code to your code. At one of the steps, the reason for the error will show up. This should for a start:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\yourname\export.csv")
    
    Dim acolumn As Long
    Dim arow As Long
    
    Dim currowstring As String: currowstring = ""
    
    For arow = 2 To 50
        For acolumn = 1 To 84
            currowstring = currowstring & Worksheets("NAME_OF_WORKSHEET").Cells(arow, acolumn) & ","
            acolumn = acolumn + 1
        Next acolumn
        
        oFile.WriteLine currowstring
        currowstring = ""
    
    Next arow

End Sub
```